# How to capture android autofill or clipboard suggestion click event?

Tags: java, android

I want to perform my own app functionality when user click on this red highlighted suggestion. How can I capture its event or callback ?
[Image of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQacd.jpg)

I tried autofill callback and editor listener but that is not working.